# How can I display all tags and values using MIT App Inventor from TinyWebDB?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am new to App Inventor and  I'm learning about TinyWebDB.

I create an application that store email address and passwords. Email Address is the tag and the password is the value.

I want to display all the data. Is is possible to display all the tags and values and how can I do this. 
I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in block to do this, but you could have a tag with a list of the other tags. Then, whenever you create a new tag, you can add it to your list of tags.

Here is an example of a login system. Accounts is a tag in the database that contains a list of all the accounts users have created. When you create an account, you get the list of accounts, add your account to it, and then save it again. Then you store your email with the password value.

[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: can you please help and show me how a little example especially that my tag is connected to my value ?